# TextField don't show float falues

Tags: flash, adobe, air

It may seems to you as a stupid question, but I really can't find out whats the problem.

I have such code:

```
var bet_value_txt:TextField = machine_mc['betValuetxt'] as TextField;
bet_value_txt.text = "2.5"; //shows 25, but I need 2.5
bet_value_txt.text = "2,5"; //shows 2,5
bet_value_txt.text = "0.25"; //shows 025, but I need 0.25
```

Whats the problem with it? Hope anybody face with such problem. Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text field uses an embedded font, make sure that the character "." is embedded too.

Comment: how can I see this in .fla file?

Comment: but wait a second: I have two elements with same settings in .fla file. Font: (ArialRoundedExtraBold) System Default Font, but in one textfield 2.5 looks good, and in another like I wrote in problem(

Comment: Assuming you are using Flash CS, click on the TextField. Then in the Properties panel, click on Font Embedding. There make sure that the correct range of characters is being embedded.

Comment: There is such property, but in both variants 'Character ranges' don't checked. but one of them can show 2.3, and another shows 23 instead 2.3

Comment: I'm using Adobe Flash CS 5.5 for this.

Comment: You need to select the character ranges in both TextFields. If it still doesn't work, it might be worth deleting both text fields and recreating them.